# drag and drop different buttons into a view (Android)?

Tags: android, image, view, buttonclick

Need to drop different buttons into a view in creating a clip art palette.
I added the image I want as the background of the button. I tried out the code and it works well, but the problem is it drops the same image for every button click.  this is my code

```
    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
    // layout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn3.setOnTouchListener(this);


    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn4.setOnTouchListener(this);


    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    }


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
             if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        status = START_DRAGGING;
        image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageBitmap(btn.getDrawingCache());
        layout.addView(image, params);

    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        status = STOP_DRAGGING;
        Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
            System.out.println("Dragging");
            image.setPadding((int) me.getRawX(), (int) me.getRawY(), 0, 0);
            image.invalidate();
        }
    }
            return false;
}
```